# List comprehension ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Tags: python

Calling a function from list comprehension is giving me a 
`ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack` error.

I have defined a function like this

```
def dateTimeStrToTimeStamp(dateTimeStr):
    """ Converts a string like '2014-03-07T19:00:00+0000' to 
    timestamp"""
    dateTimeStr, utcStr = dateTimeStr.split('+')
    dateTimeObj = datetime.strptime(dateTimeStr, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
    date_in_sec = int(time.mktime(dateTimeObj.timetuple()))
    utc_in_sec = int(utcStr[:2]) + int(utcStr[2:])
    return date_in_sec + utc_in_sec
```

I have a data which is a list of objects like this

```
[{u'id': u'1411421469112603', u'start_time': u'2014-03-09T17:00:00+0000', u'end_time': u'2014-03-09T21:00:00+0000'}, {u'id': u'519204234858802', u'start_time': u'2014-03-08T19:00:00+0000', u'end_time': u'2014-03-08T23:00:00+0000'}, {u'id': u'1393120957624703', u'start_time': u'2014-03-08T19:00:00+0000', u'end_time': u'2014-03-08T23:00:00+0000'}]
```

When I am doing this

`[ dateTimeStrToTimeStamp(event['start_time']) for event in data ]`

It gives me `ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack`

I am using python 2.7.3 Please help me , stuck here for hours

Comment: @HerrActress, I didn't get you. I want to print the timestamp values for all 3 items in my list. I don't know what I am doing wrong

Comment: I was looking in the wrong place. That's why i deleted my comment :)

Comment: With the list you posted it works. I ran it on my machine and returns `[1394380800, 1394301600, 1394301600]`

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
dateTimeStr, utcStr = dateTimeStr.split('+')
```

will give you that error when `dateTimeStr` doesn't contain `'+'` . For example, try `dateTimeStr, utcStr = 'abc'.split('+')` and you'll see the same error. So, you need to be prepared for strings that don't have the UTC component, perhaps by defaulting the UTC offset to zero. You can detect the problem by catching the exception:

```
try:
   dateTimeStr, utcStr = dateTimeStr.split('+')
except ValueError:
   utcStr = '0'
```

or if an input string without the UTC component really is an error for your function, you can provide a more useful error message:

```
try:
   dateTimeStr, utcStr = dateTimeStr.split('+')
except ValueError as e:
   raise ArgumentError('dateTimeStr {!r} has no UTC component'.format(dateTimeStr)) from e
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is being raised from your custom function, one of the strings you are passing in does not have `+` so your `split()` method doesn't return a list with two items and when you try to unpack it, you get `ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack`.

Here is a simple example of your error:

```
>>> 'ab'.split('-')
['ab']
>>> a,b = 'ab'.split('-')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```